# Xamarin says: You must add reference 'system.runtime, version=4.0.20.0'

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, mono

I have a problem by using the [ssh.net library](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/) with [Xamarin Studio 6.1](https://www.xamarin.com/) and Mono Runtime 4.6.2. By using the `client.connect()` and the `client.runcommand("...")` I get this message:

> The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'system.runtime, version=4.0.20.0, culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5...'

I tried to install Mono 4.0.2 but it didn't work because Xamarin Studio 6.1 requires at least Mono 4.6.

Does anybody have any idea to fix this?

Comment: At the moment system.runtime 4.3 is installed. An Installation of the system.runtime 4.0.20 didn't solved the problem. 
The System.Runtime.dll is linked at the following path: 

/Users/****/Projects/*****/packages/System.Runtime.4.3.0/lib/net462/system.runtime.dll

Comment: Fabian, it is usually better to not comment on your own question (unless to answer someone's comment), edit it instead by clicking the edit button (like I just did to fix some typos).